# Juniper SRX 210: Slow upload performance after enabling UTM IDP

Tags: security, juniper-srx, intrusion-prevention

I'm refining a Juniper SRX 210 UTM IDP implementation in a small business. I'm new to Junos, so I'm hoping someone will be able to point me in the best-practices direction.

The customer initially reported that tests using things like Speakeasy bandwidth test shows OK download speeds, but the upload speeds are cut in half; With a 50mbps synchronous connection, they're getting 50mbps down, but only 25mbps up. I'm hazarding a guess that this is because the SRX is inspecting these traffic types in detail as they exit the device.

The SRX 210 data sheet says it is capable of 65mbps IPS performance, but I'm not seeing that. Additionally, the log displays the following messages whenever I run a "speed test":

```
PERF_MON: RTPERF_CPU_THRESHOLD_EXCEEDED: FPC 0 PIC 0 CPU utilization exceeds threshold, current value=97
```

I'm guessing that the UTM package is somehow putting a strain on the SRX, but I don't know enough about the SRX platform to troubleshoot this properly.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Per a JNCIE who offered help:

> This behavior is expected on branch-devices which lack dedicated
>   processing for UTM and IDP functionality.

The fix is to granularly apply an IDP policy which applies only to traffic you care a lot about and judiciously choose your applied signatures based upon needs versus performance impact.